# Microsoft Bot - Node SDK: How to mention a user in Microsoft Teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

Trying to mention a user in Microsoft Teams using the NodeJs SDK:

I'm saving a ref. to the conversation and then restoring it. When restored, filling `entities` with - what I understand - it's a `Mention` object.

```js
const message = "Konnichi wa";
const conversation = await .... // restored from db
await adapter.continueConversation(conversation, async (context) => {
  const topLevelMessage = MessageFactory.text(message);
  topLevelMessage.entities = [
    {
      type: "Mention", // have tried with "mention" as well
      mentioned: context.activity.from,
      text: `@${context.activity.from.name}`,
    },
  ];
  await context.sendActivity(topLevelMessage);
});
```

this code is actually sending to the emulator an activity with the expected data:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "serviceUrl": "https://b9372952.ngrok.io",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "0c00d490-99db-11ea-a447-1de8c692dbf4",
    "name": "Bot",
    "role": "bot"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "0e086460-99db-11ea-a447-1de8c692dbf4|livechat"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "4c2e3fee-fb06-43a1-b9bb-279cc67ed6e6",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "text": "Konnichi wa",
  "inputHint": "...",
  "entities": [
    {
      "type": "Mention",
      "text": "@User",
      "mentioned": {
        "id": "4c2e3fee-fb06-43a1-b9bb-279cc67ed6e6",
        "name": "User",
        "role": "user"
      }
    }
  ],
  "replyToId": "...",
  "id": "...",
  "localTimestamp": "...",
  "timestamp": "...",
  "locale": "..."
}
```

But the shown activity is just a regular message with no mention at all. What am I missing?

- [doc.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-activities-entities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js)

=== EDIT ===

Another try has been using `TextEncoder` and `<at>` as [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js):

```js
const encodedUserName = new TextEncoder().encode(context.activity.from.name);
const mention = {
    type: "mention",
    mentioned: context.activity.from,
    text: `<at>${encodedUserName}</at>`,
};

const topLevelMessage = MessageFactory.text(`${mention.text}: ${message}`);
topLevelMessage.entities = [mention];
await context.sendActivity(topLevelMessage);
```

Comment: const topLevelMessage = MessageFactory.text(`${mention.text}: ${message}`); the @mentioned text should be given afteer the message. Could you please go through the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js#L141) here? Also Could you please go through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#-mentions) here?

Comment: I linked that same sample actually! but never would imagine that the order in the concatenation is relevant. Nuts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the final answer so anyone can copy-paste it quickly.

```js
await adapter.continueConversation(conversation, async (context) => {
    const encodedUserName = new TextEncoder().encode(context.activity.from.name);
    const mention = {
        type: "mention",
        mentioned: context.activity.from,
        text: `<at>${encodedUserName}</at>`,
    };
    const topLevelMessage = MessageFactory.text(`${message} ${mention.text}`);
    topLevelMessage.entities = [mention];
    await context.sendActivity(topLevelMessage);
});
```